# Using (“Almost”, “Nearly”, etc. + (every / any)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

I have had a look on all dictionaries for all five choices below. Unfortunately, there is no such a possibility to find out whether these words work properly in all my made examples or they would sound weird. That was why I decided to open a new thread and ask about them here. Please kindly have a look on my provided scenarios and let me know which option works within the spaces and which one doesn’t and why?

**Example #1:**

> - Willie sends me an e-mail _________ every week.

a. [almost](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/almost) 
b. [nearly](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/nearly) 
c. [practically](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/practically) 
d. [roughly](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/roughly) 
e. [approximately](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/approximately)

**Example #2:**

> - _________ everything was burned in the fire.

a. [almost](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/almost) 
b. [nearly](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/nearly) 
c. [practically](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/practically) 
d. [roughly](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/roughly) 
e. [approximately](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/approximately)

**Example #3:**

> - She’s a kind person and likes _________ everybody. Even her enemies.

a. [almost](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/almost) 
b. [nearly](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/nearly) 
c. [practically](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/practically) 
d. [roughly](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/roughly) 
e. [approximately](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/approximately)

I think all the choices above work in all of my examples properly. But I have no idea how a native speaker would think about these particular cases and what would be their choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example #1: Any of them
Example #2: a,b,c
Example #3: a,b,c

d and e do not seem to match for "everybody", "everything".

Comment: Thank you very much @Sam for the answer. I have received the answer to my original question. But may I ask you to answer my two other examples as well please? **He eats _________ anything. There is no food that he doesn’t like.** And my last example: **He loves traveling and has been _________ everywhere in the country.** My choices: **a.** almost - **b.** nearly - **c.** practically

Comment: @A-friend : "He will eat _________ anything." a,b,c. Not d,e.  "He loves traveling and has been _________ everywhere."  a,b,c.  Not d,e.